# How to adapt height of an element to another in CSS

Tags: html, css, height

I have the following HTML code

```
<div class="row info_container">
    <div class="col-md-4 info_box">
        <p class="info_text"><img src=""/>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 info_box">
        <p class="info_text"><img src=""/>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 info_box">
        <p class="info_text"><img src=""/>Some longer text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where there are 3 div, each containing an image and some text. In one of the div, the text is longer so there are 2 lines of text instead of one, resulting in a higher div.

Is there a css way to tell all the div to get the height of the bigger one ? I tried searching on google and here but couldn't find an answer without JS...

Edit : tried following css :

```
.info_container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

But it didn't work. Also tried removing the align-items property, and instead adding flex-grow:1 inside .info_box, didn't work either...

Edit 2 : aaaaand I found the mistake, it was the following line of code

```
.info_box{
height: 100%;
}
```

that was in my CSS. So, I can confirm that just adding display:flex to the container works.

Comment: Read about flexbox.

Comment: Thanks, edited my question

Comment: Could you provide the CSS as well?

Comment: I was copy/pasting it when I realized my mistake... Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Flex is your friend mate. Just add `display: flex` to the container like this:

```
.info_container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Everything else should just fall into place :)

Karen Manenez has a handy pen that will explain it nicely [here](https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
.info_container { display: flex; align-items: stretch;}
```